# Can we stop server side redirect from JSP

Tags: javascript, java, jsp

It might be a silly question to ask but please bear with me.

In my `login.jsp`, I am making an AJX call to communicate with the server using AJAX.

```
function validateLoginForm() {

    var url = "<%=(request.getContextPath())%>/Login.do";
    var username = document.getElementById("username").value;
    var password = document.getElementById("password").value;
    var params = {  "username":username,
                    "password":password
                };

    var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
    http.open("POST", url, false);
    http.setRequestHeader("X-Requested-With","XMLHttpRequest");
    http.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
  http.onreadystatechange = function() {
      debugger;
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status) {
        debugger;
    }
  };
    http.send(JSON.stringify(params));
}
```

In case of a bad login, I have the following piece of code in Java,

```
    if(loginError){

            RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher(
                        LOGIN_PAGE);
            rd.forward(request, response);
    }
```

So it again redirects back to the same login page.

If I see my AJAX response, I get the full HTML back with login error div populated like:

```
this.responseText

"


<html>
<head>
  <title>Informatica Administrator</title>
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/administrator/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" /> 
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0">
  <meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache">
  <meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate">



<script type="text/javascript">
....
...

function validateLoginForm() {
    var url = "/administrator/Login.do";
    var username = document.getElementById("username").value;
    var password = document.getElementById("password").value;

    var params = {  "username":username,
                    "password":password
                };
    var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
    http.open("POST", url, false);
    http.setRequestHeader("X-Requested-With","XMLHttpRequest");
    http.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
  http.onreadystatechange = function() {
      debugger;
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status) {
        debugger;

    }
  };
    http.send(JSON.stringify(params));

   return true;
}


</script>
<body  style='margin:0;padding:0;' id="login">
        <div class="loginBody">
          <form name="loginForm" method="POST" autocomplete="off" onsubmit="return validateLoginForm()">
          <table class='bodyClass' border=0 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0 width="100%">
              <tr>
                <td valign="top">
                  <table border=0 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0 width="100%">
                    <tr class="loginForm">
                      <td>
                        <table cellspacing="2" cellpadding="3">

                              <tr>
                                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                <td id="loginError">The login information is not valid.</td>
                              </tr>
```

**Login Information is not valid.**

The issue is, I am guessing,

**Even though the error info comes, server instructs a redirect to the login page freshly so, the fresh rendering does not show the error block.**

Can we stop this redirect or can we use the previous AJAX response error block when server does the redirect?

I am no expert, but how can we achieve this?

**UPDATE**

Piece of Java Side code...

```
public class LoginCommand extends AbstractCommand {
    // name of request parameters.
    public static final String REQUEST_PARAM_USERNAME = "username";
    public static final String REQUEST_PARAM_PASSWORD = "password";
    public static final String LOGIN_PAGE = "/login.jsp";   



    public boolean execute(Context context) throws Exception {

        ActionContext actionCtx = (ActionContext) context;
        ServletActionContext servletCtx = (ServletActionContext) actionCtx;


        HttpServletRequest request = servletCtx.getRequest();
        HttpServletResponse response = servletCtx.getResponse();

        String requestBody  = request.getReader().lines().collect(Collectors.joining());
        JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(requestBody);
        String username = (String) jsonObj.get(REQUEST_PARAM_USERNAME);
        String password = (String) jsonObj.get(REQUEST_PARAM_PASSWORD);


        ....
        ....
        ....
        else{// Trying to Login
            try {
                 // Block to execute in case of a valid login creds
            } catch(WebSSOAccountLockedException e) {
                ....
                ....
            } catch (WebSSOException e) {
                redirectURL = UserIdentifierFilter.getLoginErrorPage(request);
                loginError = true;
            } catch(Exception e) {
                redirectURL = UserIdentifierFilter.getLoginErrorPage(request);
                loginError = true;
            }
        }

        if(loginError){

                RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher(
                            LOGIN_PAGE);
                rd.forward(request, response);
        }

        return loginError;
    }
```

Comment: Can you please show me the servlet code used by you?

Comment: @UllasHunka I have put some piece of Java Side code.. I am pretty new to Java, so, please explain in case I need to change something.

Comment: What do you want in your ajax response?

Comment: @RoshanaPitigala I want the login error, definitely. But even if it should redirect back to same Login page in case of a bad login, somehow that redirect also should have the previous AJAX call's login error info. I am just not able to correlate both as a beginner.

Comment: I think you have misunderstood the purpose of AJAX. If you are using ajax you don't have to redirect the page at all

Comment: @RoshanaPitigala Thanks for the clue. Now, I can have a go at it.